# Serialize JSON nested model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and I have two models, one has a foreign key on the other model.

I created a controller and defined and index method which is working fine:

```
  def index
    @collections = Collection.all
    render json: @collections 
  end
```

Which is rendering something like this:

> [{"id":1,"title":"Collection
>   A","book_id":1,"created_at":"2016-04-10T18:41:32.709Z","updated_at":"2016-04-10T18:41:32.709Z"}]

I would like to transform that book_id field into a list of book objects, something like this:

> [{"id":1,"title":"Collection A","books": [{"book_id": 1, "title:
>   "book_title"},],"created_at":"2016-04-10T18:41:32.709Z","updated_at":"2016-04-10T18:41:32.709Z"}]

Then I tried with:

```
  def index
    @collections = Collection.all
    render :json => collections.as_json(
                  :include => { :book_title }
                )
  end
```

But is giving me syntax error and I cannot see how to do it properly in this doc `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html`

I am using Rails 4.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
  def index
    @collections = Collection.all
    render :json => @collections.as_json(
                  :include => :book
                )
  end
```

or if you would like just the :id and :title:

```
  def index
    @collections = Collection.all
    render :json => @collections.as_json(
                  :include => {:book => {:only => [:id, :title]}}
                )
  end
```

Comment: I tried your first example and it tells me undefined local variable or method `collections' for #<CollectionsController:0x00000003d73680> Did you mean? @collections Then I tried with @collections and it says Did you mean book_id?

Comment: Let me fix my answer

Comment: Hello! with @collections it gives me this error: undefined method `book' for #<Collection:0x00000002df23a0> Did you mean? book_id

Comment: Don't you have `belongs_to :book`  into your Collection class?

Comment: mmm I dont quite understand you, I am new to rails, I created the models this way: bin/rails generate model Book title:string plot:text, bin/rails generate model Collection title:string plot:text book_id:integer

Comment: if you don't have belongs_to book in your Collection class, then your attribute book_id is only another attribute like name.. If you add belongs_to, you are telling rails that is a relation one to one for that entity.

Comment: The right way to create your models was: `bin/rails generate model Book title:string plot:tex` and `bin/rails generate model Collection title:string plot:text book:references`